# Which is a better method name? GetById(int id) or Get(int id)

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices

Has there ever been a consensus on which convention is "better":

`User.GetById(int id);` or `User.Get(int id);`

i.e., is `User.Get(int id);` not *descriptive* enough? Or does is the parameter implication enough? Or is it just a matter of personal preference?

(And obviously, *consistency* across a project is more important than any particular preference.)

Comment: Presumably this is on an object?  I.e. the _what_ you are getting is easily determined by the object.  Example: `User.GetById(int id)`

Comment: @BerinLoritsch correct

Comment: I've found most of the developers I work with compeletly ignore names of things. GetById, GetByUserId, Get, or even Blargenflickel are all the same to them. They look for intellisense/auto complete pop ups, and basically nothing more.

Comment: do you get by anything other than id?  if you do, then are you consistent with id being a special case?

Comment: You didn't mention the language, how many different things one can `get`, how many ways there are to get it (or them). If there's only one kind of thing that can be retrieved and there's only one way of retrieving it, I wouldn't even name the function `get`. I would instead see if overloading the index operator is supported (some languages do, some don't) and if it makes sense from a principle of least astonishment point of view.

Comment: if `id` had its own type instead of a meaningless `int` maybe `Get(Identifier id)` would be descriptive enough.

Answer (score 12):

The main problem with a generically named Get() is it relies on there being only one kind of valid input per variable type. In most languages, you can't have methods with signatures like this:

```
Get(int id)
Get(int employee_id_card_number)
Get(int rfid_badge_number)
```

On the other hand, the following is acceptable in all typical languages:

```
GetById(int id)
GetByEmployeeIdCardNumber(int employee_id)
GetByRFIDBadgeNumber(int refid_badge_number)
```

So in short, a single Get method that relies on there only being a single identifying variable type it can take will simply not work when there exists any other variable you may want to pass in with the same type. ID is a particularly good example of this, because there are lots of "ID numbers" you might associate with a user, from RFID cards, badge numbers, four digit extensions in the phone system, etc. And it is not rare to want to Get by any such number.

Note that you do have an alternative that leaves you with Get():

```
Get(ID id)
Get(EmployeeIdCardNumber employee_id_card_number)
Get(RFIDBadgeNumber rfid_badge_number)
```

However, this only works in languages where you have the sort of strong typing of input variables that this requires - and you have to have/make types or classes for every such instance. I cannot imagine how you'd get something like this to work well in Python, for instance. No, I wouldn't recommend even attempting such a thing!

So overall, `GetByWhatever()` works in most languages, in most situations, and is quite robustly extendable - you can add new get methods without changing existing ones. I thus recommend this be the default, that you only deviate from when you have a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: This seems contrived.  None of the fields you pose as examples are semantically `int`.  You don't do math on a zip code or a social security number.

Comment: In the case of `zipcode` that only works in America.  Other countries include alphanumerics.

Comment: I don't think anyone is arguing that `GetBySomeFieldOtherThanID()` isn't semantically correct or more desirable than another `Get()` overload.  But this isn't about method overloading; the OP never mentioned retrieving entities using fields other than ID.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have seem all of these examples treated as int in real systems, but your comment makes me realize that by giving them as examples I tacitly suggest doing so is actually a good idea, so I updated the examples to be more in keeping with things that might actually be ints (ordered numbers). My general point is that the OP implicitly relies on only ever retrieving entities based on a single field, and that that field can be uniquely identified by a single base type (like int). It isn't the only problem (as your answer certainly shows other considerations), of course.

Comment: This API design actually works very well in python and is quite common. The key is to make them keyword-only arguments to force the caller to specify the argument explicitly by name. sqlalchemy does this for example

Comment: @RobertHarvey: But you're still proving the point that if both the zipcode and SSN were strings, that you'd run into the same method signature conflict anyway. This answer's adaption to an int signature might not contain the least arguable example, but the core of the answer is correct.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this really depends on whether or not you believe hidden functionality like "convention over configuration"  is desirable. If you don't believe in hidden or "implied" functionality, the abbreviated form is only valid for declarations, not calls.

```
User.Get(int id) { }
```

is completely descriptive, while

```
User.Get(4);
```

is not; it requires that you *remember* that the parameter is an id.

Unless, of course, you declare the parameter explicitly as [some languages allow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), and now it's fully descriptive again:

```
User.Get(ID: 4);
```

Or you pass a suitably named variable as the parameter:

```
User.Get(userID);
```

Personally, I lean towards being concrete, and dislike any form of "convention over configuration," in part because it requires experience with the API to work out what it is going on.  I also dislike too much indirection, so modern architectures with too much "[spooky action at a distance](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~decker/courses/280f07/paper/KingJava.pdf)" really make my head spin.

In any case, I work with [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), which has this convention:

```
connection.Get<Type>(int id) { }
```

and am quite happy with the ambiguity of calling it, because I always pass a suitably named variable:

```
connection.Get<Customer>(customerID);
```

All that said, I don't think you need the opinion of a random stranger on the internet to make this decision.  When all else fails, lean towards clarity.

Comment: Opinions of random strangers are what makes the internet!

Comment: The suitably names variables are what came to my mind first. Because, honestly, when are you ever going to write `Get(4)`. *maybe, maybe* in a test but there it's still more likely a variable. I think what would make this answer even better is a suggestion for `Get(PrimaryKey)` and `GetBySecondary(SecondaryKey)`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there is anything you could point to where that specific question has a consensus.  However, **what there is consensus on is that object, function, method names should be descriptive.**  In a sense you should be able to read the code and follow what is happening.

In general, if there is only one identifier you can get a *thing* by, then you don't have to be overly pedantic.

For example both of these are equally readable:

```
User.Get(1234);
```

and

```
User.GetById(1234);
```

Where you get into trouble is when you have two different unique identifiers you have to get something by.  The example of a `User` object works to illustrate that point.  You can obtain a `User` by the ID assigned by the database, or you can get the user by the account name.

In that case, it helps to distinguish between the two types of Gets.

```
User.GetById(1234);
User.GetByAccount('dochoffiday');
```

You might argue that the default getter is always the one by the ID so you don't need to be pedantic about that.  Honestly, that's for you and your team to come to agreement on.  Just be consistent.

Example:

```
User.Get(1234);
User.GetByAccount('dochoffiday');
```

More often than not, I find myself using `Find` as a verb for the non-standard lookups.  It's also more useful when you are pedantic about `Find`.

Example:

```
User.Get(1234);
User.FindByAccount('dochoffiday');
User.FindBySurname('Smith');
```

There's one case where you can kind of go halfway, and that's when you are dealing with `enum` values.  Mainly because what you are finding by is specified already:

```
User.FindBy(Role.Administrator);
```

It feels redundant to be completely pedantic there:

```
User.FindByRole(Role.Administrator);
```

As you use your code, you will find out whether it is expressive enough and come up with your own opinions on your own projects.  That's good.  Everything related to naming things in your programs are simply guidelines designed to help you write readable code.  Since "readable" code is a subjective concept, there can be no hard and fast rules.  Just guidelines that point you in the right direction.

Comment: `User.FindBy(Role.Administrator);` -- You renegade, you. :P

Comment: With the first call I expect users to be numbered, and users. Get(1) returns the first user etc.

Comment: I find this horrifying. Things should like different when they're different, but also things should look similar when they're similar. Having `get` and `find` do essentially the same thing with different names is just going to raise more questions: "what's the difference?" If you ask me to guess what `get` and `find` does without reading the docs, I might have guessed that `find` returns a list and `get` return a single item; or that one raises an exception when nothing is found while the other return null. I'd never expect that they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @LieRyan, Your guess to the differences is accurate.  The question was about the naming, so I didn't write out the full convention here.  With the examples I had in my answer, several `Find`s return more than one result.